# Can you change the tokens being used in the lexer in ANTLR midway?

Tags: antlr

I am trying to implement a JSP-like language in ANTLR where I can dynamically change the start and end tags while parsing.

e.g.

```
<% jet startTag="<$" endTag="$>" %>
<% this is plain text %>
<$=parsedValue$>
<$ parsedScript $>
```

Is that even possible? Or am I forced to just write my own parser to handle this requirement?

Comment: Why not "extract" the declarations/actions as a separate phase? I would not be so hasty to throw out ANTLR or other tooling :|

Comment: I can try, I am just new to ANTLR so I am trying to see it's capabilities myself.